# NGINX config not working with if condition

Tags: nginx, proxy, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have added below config under http in `nginx.conf`

```
geo $my-ip {                                                                                                                                                                       
                default "1.1.1.1/32";                                                                                                                                                   
        }
```

and in the server config I have added below

```
server {                                                                                                                                                                              
                server_name myapp-url.xyz ;                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                listen 80  ;                                                                                                                                                                  
                listen [::]:80  ;                                                                                                                                                             
                listen 443  ssl http2 ;                                                                                                                                                       
                listen [::]:443  ssl http2 ;                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                if ($my-ip) {                                                                                                                                                              
                  return 403;                                                                                                                                                                 
                }
```

So when I access `myapp-url.xyz` from `1.1.1.1` it doesn't return `403`  What could be the issue here?

**Output:**

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

**Edited:**

```
geo $geo {                                                                                                                                                                            
                default          0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                1.1.1.1/32       1;                                                                                                                                                           
        }

if (geo $arg_remote_addr $geo) {
                           return 403;
                        }
```

**Error message**

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid condition "geo" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:453
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: That configuration will return 403 for **any** IP address. If you are not getting a 403 response, Nginx is not using that server block to process the request. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files and check that the `server` block appears as written. Also, check the access and error logs.

Comment: @RichardSmith I'm using NGINX ingress controller. I manually edited the nginx.conf and added the above configs. I executed nginx -T inside the pod and the output is successful. I also see the above changes in the output. Any idea why it is not  returning 403? I'm connected to the VPN and I have whitelisted my IP in default section. Result of nginx -T added above.

Comment: Refer this [example configuration](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html), which may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: @VeeraNagireddy I have read your link and added the configuration as above (Under edited section you can find the new config). When I execute nginx -T it says the config is not valid.

Comment: Try **sudo nginx -T**.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue. If you are using NGINX ingress controller first you have to create the configmap and add the IPs.

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
data:
  http-snippet: "geo $blockthese {
    default            0;
    1.1.1.1/32   1;
    2.2.2.2/32    1;
}"
```

Apply the changes and also make sure to check the NGINX logs. And then in your Ingress add the below.

```
annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: | 
      if ($blockthese) {
        return 403;
      }
```

This way it works!